# How to merge polygons to get coordinates of final shape?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

I have list of plots numbers that should be merged into multipolygon. As a result I have to get coordinates of final shape (as multipolygon).
That is may code:

```
    # work only on layer "plots"
name = "plots"
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]
# fetch list of polygons
polyList = self.ptePlotList.toPlainText().replace(", ",",").split(',')
selected_fid = []
for poly in polyList:
      expr = QgsExpression("\"NUMBER\" = '" + poly + "'")
      it = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
      ids = [i.id() for i in it]
      selected_fid.append(ids)
selected_fid = [item for sublist in selected_fid for item in sublist]
# highlight selected polygons
layer.select(selected_fid)
# merge selected polygons and get coordinates, do not need to display
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
geoms = QgsGeometry()
for feature in selection:
      geoms = geoms.combine(feature.geometry())
mergedPolys = geoms.buffer(0,5).asWkt()
print (mergedPolys)
```

but mergedPolys is empty. What I'm doing wrong ?